# Why array_merge_recursive works like this?

Tags: php, array-merge

I have 3 arrays like this:

1st

```
Array
(
    [0695] => Array
        (
            [loan_number] => 0695
            [start_date] => 2011-12-25
        )
)
```

2nd

```
Array
(
    [0695] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
        )
)
```

3rd

```
Array
(
    [0695] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => ''
                            [qty] => ''
                            [price] => ''
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

`array_merge_recursive(array1,array2,array3)`  produces:

```
Array
(
    [0695] => Array
        (
            [loan_number] => 0695
            [start_date] => 2011-12-25
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => ''
                            [qty] => ''
                            [price] => ''
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

but if the array keys are like this

```
Array
(
    [1685] => Array
        (
            [loan_number] => 1685
            [start_date] => 2011-12-25
        )
)

Array
(
    [1685] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
        )
)

Array
(
    [1685] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => ''
                            [qty] => ''
                            [price] => ''
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

this produce result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [loan_number] => 1685
            [start_date] => 2011-12-25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => ''
                            [qty] => ''
                            [price] => ''
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Any idea why this happening and how to prevent this and get the result as first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

> If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

"0695" is not a numeric key, but "1685" is.

The [first comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#usernotes) (in fact most of the comments) on that page describes a workaround.

Comment: i tried to use first function and im using codeigniter once i call function im getting 500 internal server error

Comment: It seems you got the problem right, but I don't like your explanation. `0695` is of course a numeric value which can be easily checked with `var_dump(is_numeric(0695));` which outputs `true`. The acutal problem is that Gihana probably used the two strings `"0695"` and `"1685"` as keys. Of these two strings, the latter will get converted into an integer when used as a key by PHP. I personally would consider this a bug, or at least a stupidity by the PHP developers. Once again it can be checked with `var_dump(gettype(key(array("1685"=>null))))` which outputs `integer` instead of `string`.

Comment: Well sure, but I said "0695 is not a numeric **key**". But that's the full story, yes.

Comment: http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php   last comment works for me and thanks for pointing the error